# Can I change the default fill style of layers?

Tags: qgis, style, default

For every layer I add, I have to change the fill style.

Is it possible to define the default fill style on the project level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to open the project properties (Project>Properties... or click on the symbol left of the CRS name at the bottom right corner of the QGIS window) then select the "Default styles" tab where you can set the default style for new layers

Comment: I need clarification. In the default style for fill I don't see a Fill **style**. The Fill style I'm searching for is  'No Brush'.

Comment: @Jan You have to first select a style from the predefined set (choose the closest to what you need) then click on the edit style button (on the right of the field you just set) it will let you edit the symbol including setting no brush for the Fill style...

Answer (score 3):

You can do so for all projects, but not a single one.

Go to `properties/options`, choose the `colors` tab and in the drop-down at the top choose `new layer colors`. Here remove everything and add only the colours/styles you'd like to show up at default.

[image]

Comment: I only see color schemes here, not Fill styles. I want to set 'No Brush' as default Fill style.

Comment: If you mean by "no brush" a transparent fill, you may choose a fully transparent colour.